# Does Stack Overflow consider questions without answers to be a problem?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

I've seen some difficult but reasonable questions go unanswered (in my opinion) and its not really clear why. Zero rating, not even any bad comments, just goes without answer. Reasons can be guessed, but one asks if these questions in their individual cases would be considered "problems" because they went unanswered and un-closed.

The bounty feature is definitely very good, but maybe there should be some categorizing of unanswered questions like a) "not such a great question" b) extremely difficult c) no longer needed and not generally applicable. For example, here's an old question of mine - [Is php://input written to a temp file for large uploads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32834592/is-php-input-written-to-a-temp-file-for-large-uploads) (27 views at present time). I never did figure out the answer, but I think it is "no". In that case I could have done extensive testing if I really needed it, but better questions definitely are left unanswered.

That is just a possible thought, but my question here is if Stack Overflow yet considers (or should consider) unanswered questions to be an issue or just assumes that they are bad questions (likely a large majority are)?

Or maybe the bounty feature is an final solution to that? Definitely a good solution, I don't disagree.

Comment: Why would there be a correlation?

Comment: I don't get the question. Those questions don't get answers because either nobody can answer or nobody cares to answer. You can't throw them all on one big pile, each will have their own reasons for gathering dust. Primarily: they're abandoned by the person who asked it.

Comment: This has to be handled case-by-case, but ideally: **no**. SO (as in, the system) cannot differentiate between bad question overlooked by community with a very technical but on-topic question, and somewhat uninteresting to most people (thus no response).